# Multiplatform include best practice (qt)

Tags: c++, qt, sdl, qmake, multiplatform

i'm novice in this, can u give me some suggests ?
So i want to make a simple multi platform app with SDL and qt.

Problem is:

```
on windows_  #include <SDL2/SDL_main.h>
on mac_      #include <SDL_main.h>
```

cause on windows all libraries in folders inside "include" folder, on mac inside /Library/Frameworks
So i want to know how better make includes... is i need on all platforms make one view like  or exists better practice ? also i don't use cMake for this.

Example
Mac:

```
*.Pro file
INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks/
LIBS += -framework SDL2

#include <SDL.h>
```

Windows:

```
*.Pro file 
INCLUDEPATH += C:\SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include
LIBS += -L"C:\SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-ming32\lib" \
-lmingw32\
-lSDL2main\
-lSDL2

#include <SDL2/SDL2.h>
```

So how better make main.cpp that on all platforms it was one path or it's exists something like if win32 path  else   ?

Comment: your source should always point to the same header file, while the INCLUDEPATH in your qmake file should differ between the two systems.

Comment: ok, include path differ of system, but how to write #include inside header file correctly under all systems ?

Comment: Make your INCLUDEPATH C:/SDL2-2.0.1/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/ then you can just do `#include <SDL2.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ideal world, you should use the same code, and the buildsystem should make the buildsystem related data just work.

You could use the following scopes in your qmake project file:

```
mac: INCLUDEPATH += mac-specific-include-path
unix: INCLUDEPATH += unix-specific-include-path
win32: INCLUDEPATH += win32-specific-include-path
```

etc...

The source code will include the header files like this, then:

```
#include <SDL_main.h>
```

I would suggest to leave out the module prefix because that may hide bugs in the build system. That being said, in some projects you need to follow the convention regardless what looks more reasonable to someone.

This will ensure that if you switch port your code to another platform, you will need to make the code more complex that you probably read and modify often as the maintainer.

For sure, this also had the disadvantage that you need to reimplement this logic if you switch to a new buildsystem like `cmake` or `QBS`, but I would still recommend solving these issues on the buildsystem layer because nice source code is important.

Comment: ok, am i understand correctly, that in .h and .m must always be one include path like #include <SDL/SDL.h> no matter of system ?

Comment: @gronzzz: I would personally use SDL.h as written in the answer, but <SDL/SDL.h> will hopefully work, too.

Comment: @gronzzz: if you mean SDL.h vs. SDL2.h, you will need the ifdef in the code there, I am afraid. Unless, you create an external SDL.h wrapper around SDL2.h where there is only SDL2.h, and no SDL.h

Comment: Hm if u suggest to use without prefix, i don't understand why ? so for example i have library folder with a lot of libraries, so for using it without i need to set headers without own folders, it is a little dirty, isn't it ?

Comment: @gronzzz: I am not sure I fully understand what you mean, but it is not dirty. Actually, it will even help you in your case due to the different SDL and SDL2 folder names.

Comment: look, i have sdl.h inside SDL2 folder, and all it inside abc folder, so abc/SDL2/sdl.h , i cannot make correct include path for this header to use it like "sdl_h" and not "SDL2/sdl_h"

Comment: I am afraid, you are confusing libraries with header file in this context. I am not sure what would be dirty either way. It is, as written, even cleaner in your case where the module names may differ among platforms.